# PyQGIS - Added image URL for a legend sometimes needing manual apply

Tags: pyqgis, legend

I've made a QGIS plugin using Python. The issue I'm having is that the part of my code that adds a legend to my layer sometimes works correctly and sometimes I still have to manually open the layer properties and press "Apply" (the image URL is already there, but for some strange reason, I have to manually "Apply").
When I launch the code a second time, then it works perfectly.

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('LIMITES_ADMINISTRATIVES_EXPRESS.LATEST')[0]
legend = QgsDefaultRasterLayerLegend(layer)
url = 'https://www.geoportail.gouv.fr/depot/layers/LIMITES_ADMINISTRATIVES_EXPRESS.LATEST/legendes/LIMITES_ADMINISTRATIVES_EXPRESS.LATEST-legend.png'
layer.setLegendPlaceholderImage(url)
layer.setLegend(legend)
legend.itemsChanged.emit()
```

I've tried to tinker with the code, add a "timer" or duplicate the "itemschanged.emit()" and launch is twice, but I'm still encountering the same weird bug.

Comment: Can you try the code snippet in this github gist: https://gist.github.com/benwirf/c87452956aed7947d5724a946b5c671d If it works I will add it as an answer. It works in QGIS 3.22 & 3.26 but so does the code in your question. I think I have experienced your issue in 3.28 but I'm not able to test in the latest versions right now.

Comment: Hey ! I've tried your code, and i also added `from qgis.core import QgsDefaultRasterLayerLegend` but im getting an error saying i can't import it.
ps : im using the last version of QGIS

Comment: To me the problem is related to loading the image from the url. In that case I get the same problem only the very first time setting the legend image in a brand new project. Incidentally, the problem also occurs when loading the legend image via the layer properties dialog (very first time in a brand new project) clicking Apply or OK does not load the image to the legend. When I downloaded the image and load it from a local directory both approaches work fine. Tested in the Python console and in a plugin in QGIS 3.30. I will try to post a full answer tomorrow.

Comment: I cannot say why your import does not work for you... it works fine for me. Here is a simple example plugin you can download as a zip to install & test: https://github.com/benwirf/load-legend-image

Comment: I've tried to add the part of your code into mine... but it doesnt seem to work.
Could you look at my whole code ? (sorry im a beginner, so somethings could be not optimal) 
https://codefile.io/f/2Icsz9nfHf
The functions `import_wms` and `import_wmts` that add the WMS/WMTS Layers then add the legend.
Many thanks in advance !